# Alterar estilo de classes repetidas de forma diferente com CSS

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma classe "teste" com uma estilização e logo em seguida tenho outra class "teste". O que eu gostaria de saber é como alterar o estilo da outra class de forma diferente da primeira. O que me limita a fazer isso é que não posso alterar e nem adicionar classes, só posso usar ela do jeito que está. A unica coisa que tem diferente é que as duas classes estão dentro de containers diferentes, teria alguma forma de aplicar outro estilo no segundo exemplo, tendo como referência a class "tal2"?

```
<div class="tal">
    <div class="teste"></div>
</div>

<div class="tal2">
    <div class="teste"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só você usar um seletor diferente apontando para a class `.teste` dentro da class `.tal2`:

```css
.teste{
   color: red;
}

.tal2 .teste{
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tal">
    <div class="teste">texto vermelho</div>
</div>

<div class="tal2">
    <div class="teste">texto azul</div>
</div>
```

O seletor `.tal2 .teste` irá alterar todas as class `.teste` dentro de `.tal2`. Você pode inclusive utilizar variações. Por exemplo, para alterar apenas filhos diretos de `.tal2` que possuem a class `.teste`, utilize o símbolo `>` entre as classes:

```css
.teste{
   color: red;
}

.tal2 > .teste{
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tal">
    <div class="teste">texto vermelho</div>
</div>

<div class="tal2">
    <div class="teste">texto azul</div> <!-- filho direto -->
    <div>
       <div class="teste">texto vermelho</div> <!-- não é filho direto -->
    </div>
</div>
```